# Check for Uniqueness of Series in Groupby Object Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm struggling with how to get `transform()` to return my desired result. I would like to check if in each group whether 'missed' is unique in a given group.

Consider the follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4], 'type': ['correct', 'incorrect', 'missed', 'incorrect', 'missed', 'missed', 'correct', 'pass']})
df

  key   type
0   1   correct
1   1   incorrect
2   2   missed
3   2   incorrect
4   3   missed
5   3   missed
6   2   correct
7   4   pass
```

I'm trying to get the original dataframe to look like this. Where `only_missed` is `yes` if `missed` is the only type in the group.

```
    key type    only_missed
0   1   correct     no
1   1   incorrect   no
2   2   missed      no
3   2   incorrect   no
4   3   missed      yes
5   3   missed      yes
6   2   correct     no
7   4   pass        pass
```

I tried this but the output is unexpected:

```
a = ['correct', 'incorrect']
m = ['missed']
df['only_missed'] = df.groupby('key')['type'].transform(lambda x: 'no' if all(x.isin(a)) else ('yes' if all(x.isin(m)) else 'pass'))
df
   key  type    only_missed
0   1   correct     no
1   1   incorrect   no
2   2   missed      pass
3   2   incorrect   pass
4   3   missed      yes
5   3   missed      yes
6   2   correct     pass
7   4   pass        pass
```

This one has really stumped me as I've gone through several iterations here to try and figure out what's going on.

The help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess I am confused.  Which is your expected output?  The dataframe with 1 "pass" or the dataframe with 4 "pass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby('key')['type'].transform(
    lambda x: 'yes'
              if (x == 'missed').all() else 
              ('pass' if (x == 'pass').all() else 'no')
)
```

Comment: This did the trick. I was backwards on the logic and didn't use the `a.all()` correctly. Ditto to what @RamGhadiyaram said -- I'm not sure why this wasn't directly obvious to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.groupby('key')['type'].transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() == 1) & (x.iloc[0] == 'missed'))
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
Name: type, dtype: bool
```

And, you could mask the 'pass':

```
df.groupby('key')['type']\
  .transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() == 1) & (x.iloc[0] == 'missed'))\
  .mask(df.type == 'pass','pass')
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     pass
Name: type, dtype: object
```

And, replace True/False for yes/no:

```
df.groupby('key')['type']\
  .transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() == 1) & (x.iloc[0] == 'missed'))\
  .replace({False:'No',True:'Yes'})\
  .mask(df.type == 'pass','pass')
```

Output:

```
0      No
1      No
2      No
3      No
4     Yes
5     Yes
6      No
7    pass
Name: type, dtype: object
```

Assign to dataframe column:

```
df['only_misses'] = df.groupby('key')['type']\
                      .transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() == 1) & (x.iloc[0] == 'missed'))\
                      .replace({False:'No',True:'Yes'})\
                      .mask(df.type == 'pass','pass')
df
```

Output:

```
   key       type only_misses
0    1    correct          No
1    1  incorrect          No
2    2     missed          No
3    2  incorrect          No
4    3     missed         Yes
5    3     missed         Yes
6    2    correct          No
7    4       pass        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use booleans and add them up to create a categorical:

```
In [11]: a = pd.Series(df.type.str.match('correct|incorrect').values, df.key).groupby(level=0).transform('all')

In [12]: m = pd.Series((df.type == 'missed').values, df.key).groupby(level=0).transform('all')

In [13]: pd.Categorical.from_codes(a + 2 * m, ['pass', 'no', 'yes'])
Out[13]:
[no, no, pass, pass, yes, yes, pass, pass]
Categories (3, object): [pass, no, yes]

In [14]: df["only_missed"] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(a + 2 * m, ['pass', 'no', 'yes'])

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   key       type only_missed
0    1    correct          no
1    1  incorrect          no
2    2     missed        pass
3    2  incorrect        pass
4    3     missed         yes
5    3     missed         yes
6    2    correct        pass
7    4       pass        pass
```

This feels a *little* hacky with the `.values` (to avoid re-indexing) but should be quite efficient...

---

Upon looking again, that was the "incorrect" output, but I'll leave it there as it's essentially the same. In order to get the correct you should look at all the "pass":

```
In [21]: p = pd.Series((df.type == 'pass').values, df.key).groupby(level=0).transform('all')

In [22]: pd.Categorical.from_codes(m + 2 * p, ['no', 'yes', 'pass'])
Out[22]:
[no, no, no, no, yes, yes, no, pass]
Categories (3, object): [no, yes, pass]

In [23]: df['only_missed'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(m + 2 * p, ['no', 'yes', 'pass'])

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   key       type only_missed
0    1    correct          no
1    1  incorrect          no
2    2     missed          no
3    2  incorrect          no
4    3     missed         yes
5    3     missed         yes
6    2    correct          no
7    4       pass        pass
```